# crypto.createHash() creates security hotspot

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube, cryptojs

I have been creating hash in javascript using below code,

```
const someText ="Some Text";

crypto.createHash('sha512').update(someText,'utf-8').digest('hex');
```

or

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(someText,'utf-8').digest('hex');
```

But it has been marked as security hotspot in sonarcube "Hashing data is security-sensitive", I have tried with everything but was not able to rectify this security hotspot. Can anyone help me with this to overcome the security hotspot in sonarcube?